# std::copy hooks

Tags: c++, std, stl-algorithm

Suppose I'm using `std::copy` of similar function as `std::remove_if`, ... what it the best way to add an hook? In particular I want to log the status of the copying. At the end I want something equivalent to:

```
for(from begin to end iterator)
{
   do the copy of the container;
   cout << "." << flush;
}
```

but using `std::copy`

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Do you want something like `copy_if`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means something like given in the answers below: call certain functions on each iteration of the copy loop, which is the intent made clear by his pseudco code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's pretty much only one way: wrapping the output iterator with your own iterator that behaves exactly the same from copy's point of view, but internalyy also does the hook action.
For example, this could be some operator's implementation:

```
template< class T, bool constcv >
class HookingIterator : public std::iterator< std::forward_iterator_tag, .... >
{
public:
  reference operator* ()
  {
    dereference_hook();
    return *actual_iterator_member;
  }

  this_type& operator ++ ()
  {
    increment_hook();
    ++actual_iterator_member;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

in the constructor supply the actual iterator, and std::function objects (or plain functions/some interface instances if your compiler doesn't have std::function).

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the iterator into a structure, where you put in your hooks, for example:

```
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>
#include<numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct wrap_{

    T i;

    typedef typename T::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename T::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename T::iterator_category iterator_category;
    typedef typename T::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename T::reference reference;

    wrap_(T i) : i(i){}
    wrap_& operator++(){
        cout << "++" << endl;
        i++;
        return *this;
    }
    wrap_ operator++(int){ i++; return *this; }

    difference_type operator-( wrap_ j ){
        return i-j.i;
    }

    value_type& operator*(){
        cout << "*" << endl;    
        return *i;
    }

};

template<typename T>
wrap_<T> wrap( T i){
    return wrap_<T>(i);
}

int main(){
    vector<int> V(5);
    for (int i=0;i<V.size();i++) V[i]=i+1;

    list<int> L(V.size());
    copy( wrap( V.begin()), wrap( V.end() ), L.begin());
    assert(equal(V.begin(), V.end(), L.begin())); 
}
```

Output:

```
*
++
*
++
*
++
*
++
*
++
```

Comment: thank you. Is there a class like this ready in some library, for example in boost?